# obtaining related object from django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey

Tags: django

From a model object, I can get a related object shortcut,
using the name of the foreign key field:

```
>>> m1 = Mailbox.objects.get(pk=38)
>>> str(m1.localdomainfk)
'framailx.de'
```

But if I have the foreign key field instead of its name,
I can only get the pk of the related object:

```
>>> f1 = Mailbox._meta.get_field('localdomainfk')
>>> f1.value_from_object(m1)
7
```

Can anybody show me, how to get the related object
shortcut, if I have only the local object and the foreign key field?

Background is a generic readonly DetailView, where the actual list of fields being displayed depends on the active user (staff user sees all).

This is part of a model mixin:

```
def get_fields(self, staff):
    l = self.readonly_fields_for_staff if staff else self.readonly_fields
    return [(field.verbose_name, self.get_field_value(field), 
                self.get_related_object_from_field(field))
                        for field in l]

def get_field_value(self, field):
    if field.is_relation:
        return None
    else:
        return self._get_FIELD_display(field)

def get_related_object_from_field(self, field):
    if field.is_relation:
        return getattr(self, field.name, None)
    else:
        return None
```

The list being returned by get_fields is used by a template.

get_related_object_from_field contains the answer from Muhammad Tahir.

Comment: share your models as well.

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve? why are you trying to do this?

Comment: This is for a generic readonly DetailView, where the actual list of fields being displayed depends on the active user (staff user sees all):

Answer (score 2):

You can use [getattr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr)

```
m1 = Mailbox.objects.get(pk=38)
f1 = 'localdomainfk'
f1 = getattr(m1, f1)
```